# How to find element in appium

Tags: java, selenium, automation, appium

I am new to appium.

I am learning appium with automation of shopping app **(Flipkart)**.

I am trying to select element **5th element** from **"Recommended discount for You"** list.

In order to do that I have to make horizontal scroll to reach out to that element. But I am having problem get that container element in which elements of **"Recommended discount for You"** is present so I can fetch the `5th element`.

I guess the problem is **UI of flipkart** always getting change.

```
   driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
   Thread.sleep(3000);
   driver.scrollToExact("Recommended Offers for You");
   Thread.sleep(10000);
   // Getting error on below line
   AndroidElement ele = (AndroidElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView[@index='1']"));

  for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
   Thread.sleep(2000);
   if (ele.findElement(By.xpath("android.widget.RelativeLayout[@index='2']")).isDisplayed())
   {
       ele.findElement(By.xpath("android.widget.RelativeLayout[@index='2']")).click();
       break;
   }
   else
   {
       horizontalScroll(ele);
   }

   }

public void horizontalScroll(AndroidElement ele)
{
  Dimension size=driver.manage().window().getSize();
  int x_start=(int)(size.width*0.60);
  int x_end=(int)(size.width*0.30);
  int y=130;
  ele.swipe(SwipeElementDirection.RIGHT,x_end,y,4000);
}
```

I am using `uiautomator` to `find elements`. Here is the **screenshot of UI**.

[image]

I have following questions:

1. What is best way to find elements if UI of app is as displayed.
2. Which app should I automate in order to learn appium.
3. How to automate app if UI of app is always getting change

**Please Help! Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 2):

1. Best(or rather the fastest) way to locate an element in the app is using  the **resource-id**. If the *resource-id* is unavailable/same you have to locate it using **xpath**
2. If you want to Learn *Appium* you can start by following these tutorials by *Mukesh Otwani* here is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gC1IDmL6d9w&list=PL6flErFppaj20yvWkrYv6yO_I3jJWvYTj&index=4)
3. If the UI keeps updating the only way tackle this is keep updating your script with the changes.

Hope it helps!

Comment: What if there are multiple resource having same resource_id. Because I am seeing multiple resource having same resource_id

Answer (score 1):

In here, I see the element has a resource-id. Why not use that ?

1. What is best way to find elements if UI of app is as displayed.
   Always, finding element by resource id is a preferred method. Because, it finds the element faster than xpath. Also, if there is an element added in between, the xpath varies, because the element in the hierarchy changes.
2. Which app should I automate in order to learn appium. 
   Any native app, to begin with use appium provided UICatalog for iOS, and apps from playstore for android.
3. How to automate app if UI of app is always getting change
   Scalable solution to automate UI app involves creating page objects, maintaining locators in one place and not spread out through out the test cases etc. It depends on the magnitude of change, is it the navigation that has changed, the element hierarchy that has changed etc. The resource id based selection is always preferred, which sort of reduces the change in automation script, if there is a layout change in the app. But I am afraid there is no single method to tackle this issue.

Comment: What if there are multiple resource having same resource_id. Because I am seeing multiple resource having same resource_id

Comment: In a RecyclerView, items will very commonly have the same resourceIds since they are the same View. Unless you are using unique items to populate the RecyclerView, which would go against the RecyclerView's intention.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple UI elements with same resource id you can make use of index along with resource-id.

```
WebElement element=driver.findElements(By.id("your_id")).get(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In android if the view is any kind of list view , all the elements will have same id , so in that case u can use the name to tap on it or u can create xpaths and use it to perform ur actions